# How to backup mail with exim4 server

Tags: backup, exim

I have a little exim4 mail server with local delivery to /var/mail folder.
How can I backup mails? Is it enought to simply save all /var/mail folder?
In this case, how to restore?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of that folder are just normal files. Back them up using whatever backup software you'd like. Then restore them as you would any other file.

Comment: There are no other vital exim file, indexes, or other out of that folder? Thank you

Comment: @Tobia: Naturally, you *should* need to backup stuff like user accounts, passwords etc. if that's applicable for your envirornment, let alone the rest of the system ...